# Compare contact and select on click

Tags: android

i am creating app in which i have to compare my device contact to server data contact.i am doing this but only last data is coming,but i want to make comparison with every device contact to server contact.I am able to fetch data from device and from server but i don't know how to compare.
Here phonenumber is no coming from phonecursor and second is server data.

```
Objects.equals(phoneNumber, jsonObject1.getString("mobile"))
```

after the comparison i want to select any five contact from list and send it to another fragment.i don't know how to select item from recyclerview list.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to store your all contact into DB.

then,

```
ArrayList<String> foundNumb = new ArrayList();

for (int A = 0; A < DB_Contact_List.size(); A++) {
  // get contact from DB list one by one
   DBContactBean dbDataBean = DB_Contact_List.get(A);

   String DbNumb = dbDataBean.getmNumber().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
   String ServrNumb = "";
   ServerContactBean serverDataBeanM = null;
   boolean found = false;
   int BBB = 0;

   if (!DbNumb.equals("")) {

   innerLoop:
   for (int B = 0; B < Server_Contact_List.size(); B++) {
    // get contatct from Server list one by one             
   ServerContactBean serverDataBean = Server_Contact_List.get(B);
   BBB = B;

   serverDataBeanM = serverDataBean;
   ServrNumb = serverDataBean.getPh_phone().replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    // compare it
   if (DbNumb.equalsIgnoreCase(ServrNumb)) {
            found = true;
            break innerLoop;
          }
  }
      if (found) {
                // if  found do your task
                foundNumb.add(DbNumb);
      } else {
                // not found
      }
 }
}
```